# Magento Loading Time (ttfb over 1.6 Minutes)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

We increased our products from 12k to 50k.

Now we're faceing a huge loading time issue. Sites are loading over 1-2 minutes. It seems like the first ttfb takes much to long and our developers can't find a solution/reason for that. someone knows a solution for this or someone who eveb could fix it? (paid)

[Loading Time in Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bUNp.jpg)

Slow example url would be: https://gear2game.ch/unterhaltungselektronik/tv-home-cinema/tv.html

Also good to know, the homepage is fast, but all categories and products are slow :(

Best regards

Sandro

Answer (score 0):

When the homepage is fast, but categories and products are slow, that is frequently an indication that way too much data is being loaded somewhere in a custom module, or you're not making use of indexers (which are a necessity with 50k products).

Slow ttfb also indicates that it's an issue on your backend (and given you just added a bunch of products, I'd say it's because some of the settings in Magento to handle large amounts of data are not enabled).

These are the things I'd start with:

- Have you reindexed?
- Are you using flat tables?
- Are your caches enabled?
- Are you using the Magento swatch module? This is notoriously bad with many products.

Answer (score 0):

With a 50K products you should really think about Varnish.

Here are some useful links :
https://varnish-cache.org/
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/turpentine-varnish-cache.html